# R: cambiar los colores de un DCA

Tags: r

A partir de este archivo:

```
     https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jmZG-nyt707AhHZSSl4dHLIxK0nZ5qyX
```

y estos paquetes

```
     library(vegan)
     library(reshape2)
```

Y tomando este código para realizar esta gráfica, me gustaría saber como puedo cambiar los colores de cada punto a estos colores
"light blue" en el grupo Oak ,"mediumorchid" en el grupo wasteland,"green" en el grupo Edge y "orange" en el grupo Crop

```
 raw.data <- read.csv("Raw_Data_MJM.csv", header = TRUE)
 raw.site.spp.dca <- acast(raw.data, collection + habitat ~ taxon, fill = 0)

 raw.site.hab <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(raw.site.spp.dca), "_"), "[[", 2); head(raw.site.hab)

 site.des <- c("C1F", "C2F", "C3F", "C4F", "Wl1F", "Wl1F2", "Wl1P", "Wl1P2", "Wl2F", "Wl2F2", "Wl2P", "Wl2P2", "Wl3F", "Wl3F2", "Wl3P", "Wl3P2", "Wl4F", "Wl4F2", "Wl4P", "Wl4P2", "H1P", "H2P", "H3P", "H4P2", "H5P2", "H6P2","Ed1F", "Ed1F2", "Ed1P", "Ed1P2", "Ed1V", "Ed1V2", "Ed2F", "Ed2F2", "Ed2P", "Ed2V", "Ed2V2", "Ed3F", "Ed3F2","Ed3P", "Ed3P2", "Ed3V", "Ed3V2", "Ed4F", "Ed4F2", "Ed4P", "Ed4P2", "Ed4V2", "M11V", "M12V", "M1V", "M2V", "M3V", "M4V", "M5V", "M7V", "M8V", "M9V", "Oa1F", "Oa1F2", "Oa1P", "Oa1P2", "Oa2F", "Oa2F2", "Oa2P", "Oa2P2", "Oa3F", "Oa3F2", "Oa3P", "Oa3P2", "Oa4F", "Oa4F2", "Oa4P", "Oa4P2", "Z1V", "Z2V", "Z3V", "Z4V")
 length(site.des)



 plot(raw.dca, 
 type = "n",
 cex.main = 0.75,
 cex.lab = 1.25,
 axes = TRUE, 
 cex.axis = 1.0,
 yaxt = "n",
 xlim = c(-6, 6), 
 ylim = c(-4, 4),
 #main = "Raw data", 
 xlab = "DCA1 (0.353 total variance)", 
 ylab = "DCA2 (0.243 total variance)")

 axis(2, at=c(-4, -2, 0, 2, 4), tick = TRUE, cex.axis = 0.75)
 points(raw.dca, col = as.integer(as.factor(raw.site.hab)), 
   pch = as.integer(as.factor(raw.site.hab)))
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomando un ejemplo de la red

```
library (vegan)

veg.data <- read.delim ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zdealveindy/anadat-r/master/data/vltava-spe.txt', row.names = 1)
env.data <- read.delim ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zdealveindy/anadat-r/master/data/vltava-env.txt')

DCA <- decorana (veg = log1p (veg.data))

ordiplot (DCA, display = 'sites', type = 'n')
points (DCA, 
        pch = env.data$GROUP,
        col = c("orange", "green", "lightblue", "mediumorchid")[env.data$GROUP]
        )
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Explicación:

Queremos configurar los colores en función de la variable `env.data$GROUP`, pero no queremos cualquier color sino ciertos en particular, esta variable tiene estos datos:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4
> length(env.data$GROUP)
[1] 97
> env.data$GROUP
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 2 1 3 3 2 3 1 1 1 3 1 2 3 1 1 4 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 1 1
[40] 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 4 4 4 4 4 1 1 3 1 1 4 1 1 2
[79] 4 4 4 2 4 4 1 2 1 1 1 3 1 3 3 1 1 1 1
```

Es decir, son 4 grupos repartidos en 97 observaciones, lo que vamos a hacer es darle a cada observación un color en particular y lo hacemos con una operación de indexado simple, sobre el vector de colores:

```
> head(c("orange", "green", "lightblue", "mediumorchid")[env.data$GROUP], 20)
 [1] "orange"    "orange"    "orange"    "orange"    "green"     "green"    
 [7] "lightblue" "lightblue" "orange"    "orange"    "green"     "orange"   
[13] "lightblue" "lightblue" "green"     "lightblue" "orange"    "orange"   
[19] "orange"    "lightblue"
```

Esto lo podemos hacer así de sencillo por que `env.data$GROUP` es numérico y ya nos sirve para hacer la selección, en tu caso:

```
> head(raw.site.hab,20)
 [1] "Crop"      "Crop"      "Crop"      "Crop"      "Wasteland" "Wasteland"
 [7] "Wasteland" "Wasteland" "Wasteland" "Wasteland" "Wasteland" "Wasteland"
[13] "Wasteland" "Wasteland" "Wasteland" "Wasteland" "Wasteland" "Wasteland"
[19] "Wasteland" "Wasteland"
> head(c("orange", "green", "lightblue", "mediumorchid")[as.integer(as.factor(raw.site.hab))], 20)
 [1] "orange"       "orange"       "orange"       "orange"       "mediumorchid"
 [6] "mediumorchid" "mediumorchid" "mediumorchid" "mediumorchid" "mediumorchid"
[11] "mediumorchid" "mediumorchid" "mediumorchid" "mediumorchid" "mediumorchid"
[16] "mediumorchid" "mediumorchid" "mediumorchid" "mediumorchid" "mediumorchid"
```

Los valores son cadenas, por lo que simplemente las convertimos en un `factor` y usamos el índice numérico de cada valor para reemplazar por el color. Lo que restaría es pasarle a `points` este vector por medio del parámetro `col`.

Comment: funciona a la perfección, muchas gracias patricio

Answer (score 2):

Una alternativa a la respuesta de Patricio Moracho es extraer los scores del objeto `decorana`, pasarlos a data.frame y hacer el gráfico con ggplot. La "desventaja" es que tenés que explorar el objeto y encontrar ahí los coeficientes. Las ventajas son:

1. Tenés que explorar el objeto `decorana`. Muchas veces haciéndolo se encuentran cosas interesantes.
2. Al hacer el gráfico con `ggplot` tenés control completo sobre el gráfico.

   - Si estás trabajando en una publicación en la que hay otros gráficos al usar los `themes` obtenés una apariencia visual más homogénea.
   - Podrías agregar más series de datos al mismo gráfico.
   - etc.

## Extraer los scores de un objeto `decorana`

> Reciclo parte de la respuesta de Patricio.

```
library (vegan)

veg.data <- read.delim ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zdealveindy/anadat-r/master/data/vltava-spe.txt', row.names = 1)
env.data <- read.delim ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zdealveindy/anadat-r/master/data/vltava-env.txt')

DCA <- decorana (veg = log1p (veg.data))
```

Con el objeto DCA listo la forma más simple de estraer las coordenadas es tomarlas del sumario:

```
sumario_DCA <- summary(DCA)

#Miras la estructura del objeto para ver dónde está la información que te interesa.
# En Rstudio podrías usar View(DCA)

str(sumario_DCA)
```

`sumario_DCA` es una lista y en la ubicación `sumario_DCA$site.scores` están las coordenadas de sitio. Ahora va todo en tubería, aunque podrías hacerlo paso a paso.

## Generar el gráfico

```
sumario_DCA$site.scores %>%               #Esto es una matriz
  as.data.frame() %>%                     #Que aquí paso a data.frame
  mutate(grupo = env.data$GROUP,          #Agrego la información de grupo del data.frame con los datos. En ambos casos el largo es 97 y el orden el mismo.
         grupo = as.factor(grupo)) %>%    #Paso a factor para que ggplot haga una escala discreta.
  ggplot(aes(x = DCA1, 
             y = DCA2, 
             color = grupo, 
             shape = grupo)) + #por si va a imprenta en blanco y negro. Redundante.
  geom_point() +                                   #Agrego los puntos
#Personalizo el gráfico. No es estrictamente necesario.
  theme_minimal() + 
  labs(title = "Detrended Correspondence Analisys", 
       subtitle = "It's just CA for biologists", 
       caption = "Elaboración propia
                  Datos David Zelený")
```

## Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias mpaladino, muy completa la respuesta y funciona perfectamente